# Can't get the :not selector to work on in my jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, click, live

I'm new to HTML and jQuery and need some help....

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="conteiner">
    <div class="calendar" style=""> </div>
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="avatar read"></div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="activity mytivits-act"></div>
        <div class="comments"></div>
        <div class="text-conteiner">
            <h3>test remind</h3>
            <span class="grey"></span>
            <span class="send-reminder">Remind</span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to filter out clicks from the .live function below  when user is clicking on Remind link (as I have a separate function to handle this case)

```
<span class="send-reminder">Remind</span>
```

using this jQuery line below but it doesn't work...any idea how to fix it?

```
$('.text-conteiner:not(.send-reminder)').live('click', function(e){
    ...
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can stop the event propagation. `:not()` will not work here.

```
$('.text-conteiner').live('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7pb2/)**

for example, you can also do like below:

```
$('.text-conteiner').live('click', function(e){
    alert('container');
});
$('.send-reminder').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('remainder');
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7pb2/3/)**
​

#### Note

If it's possible then instead of `.live()` use `.on()` for delegate event handling with jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use the .live() since I render these objects using ajax.

Comment: Your first code helped! Thank you SO much for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` on the `send-reminder` span.

```
$('.text-conteiner span.send-reminder').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}));
```